# How to make simple mathematical operations and displaying the result in a textbox

Tags: c#, math

I know is a rather simple question but I just can't find an appropriate example in google or anywhere.

I've got this piece

```
int numberOfPlays = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
numberOfPlays = (numberOfPlays++);
textBox2.Text = (numberOfPlays.ToString()); 
MessageBox.Show(numberOfPlays.ToString());
```

So basically what I want to do is to get the value of the textBox2, make it an integer and then add 1 to it.

I can't think of any more details right now, so if i'm not clear enough please ask

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
numberOfPlays = (numberOfPlays++);
```

You need just

```
numberOfPlays++;
```

Otherwise you are overwriting the changes with the old value (note that the *value* of `(numberOfPlays++)` is the "old" one, before increment).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 numberOfPlays = (numberOfPlays++);
```

to just

```
 numberOfPlays++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
numberOfPlays++;
```

Otherwise the [post increment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) is applied (as the name says) **after** the value of `numberOfPlays` is assigned to `numberOfPlays` again - which will not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what the others have said,

```
numberOfPlays++
```

Is the same as

```
numberOfPlays += 1
```

Is the same as

```
numberOfPlays = numberOfPlays + 1
```